# Cannot deploy NextJS project, working around localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my nextJs project, through vercel deploy. However, I am running into the issue that because my code calls localhost:3000/api, the code won't make it past the npm run build, as the api is not currently running at build time.

Calling the productsCollection Api returns a json object of all the products available, using prisma.products.findMany().

So instead, I tried

```
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/api/productsCollection`)
```

which still doesn't work.

```
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from frame-website-mv3sa1ws4-bobrandy13.vercel.app/api/productsCollection
00:20:01.357        at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14062:11)
00:20:01.358        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
00:20:01.358        at async getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/products/[products].js:85:17)
00:20:01.358        at async buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:598:33)
00:20:01.359        at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:930:115
00:20:01.360        at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20) {
00:20:01.360      [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
00:20:01.360          at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
00:20:01.360          at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
00:20:01.360          at new URL (node:internal/url:645:5)
00:20:01.360          at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6914:25)
00:20:01.360          at fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13228:25)
00:20:01.361          at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14060:18)
00:20:01.361          at fetch (node:internal/process/pre_execution:237:25)
00:20:01.361          at getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/products/[products].js:85:23)
00:20:01.361          at buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:598:39)
00:20:01.361          at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:930:121 {
00:20:01.361        input: 'frame-website-mv3sa1ws4-bobrandy13.vercel.app/api/productsCollection',
00:20:01.361        code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
00:20:01.361      }
00:20:01.362    }
```

I also tried just having fetch('/api/productsCollection'), by utilising serverless functions, but it still doesn't work. The error I get is fetched failed, invalid url.

How else could I get around this problem?

I expected the code to correctly retrieve the products without using localhost:3000.

Steps that have been tried are above.

Comment: have you tried to inform the protocol? http:// https:// or even //

Comment: i tried adding https:// before the process.env.VERCEL_URL to no avail.

Comment: how did you fix this issue ? @KevinHuang